# Google Search Console - get property set name

Tags: google-api, google-search-api

I work with "Search Console API v3" now. 
When I use "webmasters.sites.list" method, I get site URLs and propery sets. Propery set for expample - "sc-set:B9KPftMA4RltK1LS61GR2g".

But I can't find any way to get REAL NAME for property set using API.

I can't show this id "sc-set:B9KPftMA4RltK1LS61GR2g" to client instead normal name.

Example of response:

```
"siteEntry": [ { "siteUrl": "example.com", "permissionLevel": "siteRestrictedUser" },
               { "siteUrl": "sc-set:2d0rU0BQiIHsmCH-HGZ1KA", "permissionLevel": "siteRestrictedUser" } 
             ]
```

Comment: I can't find any methods in API to get infromation about propery set's parameters. (property set name for example)

Comment: Example of response:
 "siteEntry": [
  {
   "siteUrl": "https://www.example.com/",
   "permissionLevel": "siteRestrictedUser"
  },
  {
   "siteUrl": "sc-set:2d0rU0BQiIHsmCH-HGZ1KA",
   "permissionLevel": "siteRestrictedUser"
  }
 ]

Comment: You cant update these.  Once they are inserted thats the data that is their.

Answer (score 0):

when you call [sites.list](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites/list) it returns a list of [site resources](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites#resource) which contain

```
 {
   "siteUrl": "http://www.daimto.com/",
   "permissionLevel": "siteOwner"
  },
```

There is no way to get any additional information about the site than that.   What i am not able to understand is why you appear to be getting back some kind of id.

Comment: I need display to our clients site url or set name and some it's metrics. I can't find any methods to get infromation about propery set's parameters.  "http://www.daimto.com/ - is a clear information for user, "sc-set:B9KPftMA4RltK1LS61GR2g" - is not clear for user.

Comment: I would suggest that the fact that it says siteRestrictedUser may have something to do with it.    You can only see the data that the current loged in user has permission to see.

Comment: I create this property set with this permissions by GUI. Real name of this set ("sc-set:2d...") is "Test Group Set". But I can't get this name trough API.

Comment: You apear to be getting that back in your response now ("siteUrl": "sc-set:2d0rU0BQiIHsmCH-HGZ1KA")